# SFTP & fingerprint

Tags: c++, sftp, fingerprint, rfc

Пишу обертку на С++ над libssh2 для работы с SFTP. В процессе анализа прилагаемых примеров заметил, что в одном месте вызывается получение "отпечатка" от сервера:

`fingerprint = libssh2_hostkey_hash(session, LIBSSH2_HOSTKEY_HASH_SHA1)`

Но потом, в коде переменная `fingerprint` вообще нигде не участвует. Ну только если назвать ее "участием" то, что ее распечатывают на `stdout`.

**Вопросы**

1. Получение отпечатка - это обязательный этап для соединение с SFTP?
2. Есть ли RFC для SFTP, или только спецификация от IETF?
3. Есть что-то посвежее, нежели "[SSH File Transfer Protocol, Draft 13, июль 2006](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13)"?

Comment: Я полагаю, его печатают на экран, чтобы юзер визуально его сравнил с правильным.

Comment: Т.е. если у меня вся инициализация и логин будут "под капотом", мне это не нужно, и можно пропустить?

Comment: SFTP — глючное чудовище. Не знаю, результат ли это кривостей в реализациях или в спецификации, но только вопросов "у меня не работает SFTP" гораздо больше, чем вопросов "у меня не работает SCP". SCP работает всегда.

Comment: Ну мне выбирать не приходится - партнер выставил ТУ, остальное его не парит. Пока ... "полет" нормальный - логин по ключам уже проходит норм. Но еще поле не паханное...

Comment: Копал копал ssh, очень понравилось вот это http://www.mnin.org/write/2006_sshcrypto.html (драфт читал, очень нечитабельное). По идее - запрос отпечатка нужен что бы убедится что шифрование установлено. Возможно это было как типа "проверка" по хешу, что соидинение успешно (по аналогии с другими протоколами). Я у себя попробую пропустить пакет. У этих mnin кстати этого пакета нету.

Comment: Спасибо! По возможности почитаю.